# Getting repetitive pattern from multi-step-ahead prediction on timeseries data using LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

We are using `LSTM` to learn sequences on timeseries data. Ask is to do multi-step-ahead predictions using the trained models. We are using a standard multi-layered `Sequential` model.

The model learns the pattern nicely and can re-play the entire trained data closely.
However, when it comes to doing multi-step-ahead prediction, it seems to fall into some sort of repetitive pattern. (please see the second graph in the Colab notebook)

The idea for doing multi-step-ahead prediction is:

1. Take `timestep_count` existing sequence, run `predict()` on it and get the `y_dimension` outputs:

   X<sub>t-9</sub>, X<sub>t-8</sub>, X<sub>t-7</sub>, X<sub>t-6</sub>, X<sub>t-5</sub>, X<sub>t-4</sub>, X<sub>t-3</sub>, X<sub>t-2</sub>, X<sub>t-1</sub>, X<sub>t</sub> ==> Model ==> P<sub>t+1</sub>, P <sub>t+2</sub>,...P <sub>t+m</sub>
2. Take the `y_dimension` predicted values (`P`) and push them at the end of `X`.

   X<sub>t-7</sub>, X<sub>t-6</sub>, X<sub>t-5</sub>, X<sub>t-4</sub>, X<sub>t-3</sub>, X<sub>t-2</sub>, X<sub>t-1</sub>, X<sub>t</sub>, P<sub>t+1</sub>, P<sub>t+2</sub> ==> Model ==> P<sub>t+3</sub>, P <sub>t+4</sub>,...P <sub>t+2+m</sub>
3. Run this new `X` through the same cycle until we get the `future_steps` predictions required.

The problem is this technique generates a repetitive pattern as seen in the second graph in colab notebook.

Is this the right approach to do multi-step-ahead prediction?

Other solution is to train the model to give more number of `future_predictions`. But our requirement is to predict many timesteps in the future and we are not sure if this is the right approach.

Colab link to working sample: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ImLBSmM875OouCLoCwh6JeFKFCmwLbby

Please note: The colab notebook has limited training set. In actual production we train on 10000 to 50000 samples and still see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After analysing your code, I think the problem is in the way you build the input for the model to test it. You use a different process that involves a different random function.

As another observation... the data you are trying to predict is completely random...no relationship between the inputs and outputs. There must be a way to relate input and output(right?). Otherwise what are you modeling?

I created an alternative dataset and problem formulation to yours. It's related and you can take a look at it [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Atzc6vkzsrIWju2hVVsrzdssih7Rn2_K).

Comment: I have updated the question. In production, we train on a much larger data set.

Comment: @CodeRain by repetitive you mean "constantly" increasing?

Comment: yes, either it keeps increasing or it keeps decreasing.

Comment: thanks for the notebook. However am afraid it does not have the "multi-step-ahead" prediction part. I see that your model is predicting 5 future timesteps. But we would like to predict more timesteps and for this we feed the output back into the input and repeat this pattern. And that is when we are seeing the problem.